# Trying to create an Htree using Recursion in Java, unable to get it to do more than one corner

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm currently taking a class in Java and our professor is having us write a program using recursion to build an "Htree" which is just an H with smaller H's on every corner of the first, and down as many levels as the user specifies. So far I have it recursively creating the FIRST corner, but I can't seem to figure out how to change it so it will do all four corners. Here is my code:

```
package assignment3;

public class Htree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int SIZE = 512;

        // Output and entry take place in the console window

        Turtle.create(SIZE, SIZE);

        int xCenter = SIZE / 2;
        int yCenter = SIZE / 2;

        int x = 4;
        recursive(xCenter, yCenter, x);
    }

    private static void recursive(int xCenter, int yCenter, int x) {
        int x2 = x - 1;

        if (x2 < 0) {
            return;
        }
        int left = xCenter - xCenter / 2;
        int right = xCenter + xCenter / 2;
        int top = yCenter - yCenter / 2;
        int bottom = yCenter + yCenter / 2;
        int middle = yCenter;

        Turtle.fly(right, middle);
        Turtle.go(left, middle);
        Turtle.fly(right, top);
        Turtle.go(right, bottom);
        Turtle.fly(left, top);
        Turtle.go(left, bottom);
        recursive(left, top, x2);

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

And it's supposed to look something like this:
[image: Htree]

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger and stepped through the code to see what's happening? Did you write the code or get it from somewhere else? Do you understand what the code is currently doing?

Comment: I wrote it, and when I wrote it I figured it would do all four corners but now I know that the positions I'm giving it is just the bottom left points, never any other corner I just don't know how to change it to get it to draw the other corners. I can't think how to get it to change spots without screwing up.I'll try debugger now though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code like

```
    int left = xCenter - xCenter / 2;
    int right = xCenter + xCenter / 2;
```

is problematic.  Suppose the X centers for second-level H's should be at x=2 and x=6.  For the lefthand H you compute left=1, right=3, so it would be 2 units wide.  But for the righthand H you compute left=3, right=9, so it is 6 units wide.  Conclusion:  your recursive routine needs another parameter, to specify width, and you would use formulas like left=xCenter-wide/2, right=xCenter+wide/2.

Here is pseudocode for an easy way to do the four different recursive calls (with `drawH(xCenter, yCenter, wide, deep)` used in place of your `recursive(left, top, x2);` function):

```
p = q = 1
for i in {1..4}:
    drawH(xCenter+p*size/xratio, yCenter+q*size/yratio, wide/2, deep-1)
    q = p*q; p = -p;
```

*Correction and note, May 2016:* The last line of pseudocode, `q = p*q; p = -p;`, produces (p, q) pairs {(1, 1),  (-1, 1),  (1, -1),  (-1, -1)} for the four bars of the H.